# How to route/replace HVAC plenum/trunk lines through a poorly designed foundation wall hole with a gas pipe in the way on the other side

Tags: hvac, furnace, foundation, ducts, crawlspace

New homeowner of a 1959 constructed house. Surprisingly, only 4 owners (including myself), with the last 2 each having it for about 20 yrs and each seemed to be DIYers - not necessarily choices I would have made some of the time with their improvements:)

We have a packaged A/C and gas-powered furnace unit (Goodman GPG142080M41AB) sitting on the exterior of the house, with the supply and return plenums connecting to the trunk on the outside as well. These are 16" flex ducts which route down through the crawlspace foundation hole, underneath the gas supply line (which is curiously located in front of the hole, reducing the available space) and in the case of the supply, connect to a rigid trunk duct.

The supply is likely >15yrs old and needs to be replaced, as it is quite leaky and spilling conditioned air into the crawlspace. This bend to get down into the crawlspace clearly crimped the flex duct of the return, and seems to have caused excess pressure in the supply flex duct at the juncture points driving a lot of leakiness.

I would like to not use flex duct and only use rigid for the trunk. Although it would be ideal to have a true straight shot, I don't think it is possible without lowering the HVAC unit and rerouting the gas line to get it out of the way.

**My question:** what would you recommend I do? Replace with flex duct? Are there special tapered rigid ducts? Should I abandon this hole and move the unit somewhere else? Should I dig the unit down to level w/ the crawl space entrace?

**The relevant dimensions are as follows:**

*Crawlspace foundation hole:* Height 16", width ~38" (jagged edges)

*HVAC supply & return duct openings:* 16"x16"

*Distance from bottom of HVAC duct opening to bottom of unit:* ~5" (amount to lower HVAC unit to align duct openings w/ crawlspace hole)

Images
[image]

Diagram
[image: `]

Comment: Think digging a hole to drop the unit would only end up being a collection hole for water to go and flooding the unit.   Unless you could dig enough away so unit would on high ground, compared to surrounding ground.